# <IntelliJ Idea> Warning: Redeclared <each_name> defined above without usage

Tags: python, intellij-idea

### I have a file containing names like this:

### Aang
Zuko
Appa
Katara
Sokka
Momo
Uncle Iroh
Toph

I extract the names as a list of each line from the above text file, as a list of lines, each containing the '\n'. (ex: 'Aang\n')

To remove the new-line character, I tried using the strip method as shown below. However, for some reason it does not work, and it shows this warning in IntelliJ Idea: "Redeclared <each_name> defined above without usage."

```
with open(file="./Input/Names/invited_names.txt", mode="r") as names_file:
    names = names_file.readlines()

for each_name in names:
    each_name = each_name.strip()
print(names)
```

But this error does not occur for this code:

```
with open(file="./Input/Names/invited_names.txt", mode="r") as names_file:
    names = names_file.readlines()

for i in range(len(names)):
    names[i] = names[i].strip()
```

Can anyone please help me understand why?